# shell script -S and -Sd code not working correctly

Tags: shell

I have the following code:

```
#Option -s for each set of files with the same name, presents sorted by size#

elif [ $1 = "-S" ]
then
    shift
    for i in $*
    do
        find $i -type f -print|while read F1
            do

                basename "${F1}"
            done | sort | uniq -d | while read F2
            do
                    find $i -type f -name "${F2}" -exec ls -l -S -R '{}' \;
            done        
        done

#Option -d performs sorting in descending order.

elif [ $1 = "-d" ]
then
    shift
    for i in $*
    do
        find $i -type f -print|while read F1
            do

                basename "${F1}"
            done | sort | uniq -d | while read F2
            do
                    find $i -type f -name "${F2}" -exec ls -l '{}' \;
            done        
        done
```

I was supposed to print them by size with the command `-S` and then in descending order with `-Sd`. My output doesn't seem to do that. At this point I can't figure out what is wrong in my code.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 33 Out  7 20:27 aa/cc/t1
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 8 Out  7 20:36 aa/t1
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out  8 08:16 aa/cc/t2
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out  8 08:15 aa/t2
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 16 Out  8 08:16 aa/cc/t4
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out 10 12:53 aa/dd/t4
```

Comment: Can you describe "not working" in more detail? What is some expected output, and what is the actual output? See [mcve].

Comment: when you use the command -S it should output something like this  

-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 8 Out  7 20:36 aa/t1  
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 33 Out  7 20:27 aa/cc/t1  
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out  8 08:16 aa/cc/t2  
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out  8 08:15 aa/t2  
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 0 Out 10 12:53 aa/dd/t4  
-rw-r--r-- 1 quetzal quetzal 16 Out  8 08:16 aa/cc/t4  

and when -Sd is used it should output the files in the descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the sort like this:

```
elif [ $1 = "-d" ]
then
shift
for i in $*
do
    find $i -type f -print|while read F1
        do

            basename "${F1}"
        done | sort -r | uniq -d | while read F2
        do
                find $i -type f -name "${F2}" -exec ls -l '{}' \;
        done        
    done
```